# create UIImage from UILabel?

Tags: iphone, uiimage, uilabel

I can use the following code to create image from UIView.
However the same code won't capture the text of UILabel.(it captures label's background color though)
How can I create image of UILabel with text?

```
CGSize size = view.bounds.size;
CGContextRef context = CreateARGBBitmapContext(size);
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
[view.layer renderInContext: context];
CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
CGContextRelease(context);
```

Comment: UILabel is just a subclass of UIView, so you should need just replace `view` with `label` (the name) in the above code. What is the code that's not working?

Comment: ah, shoot me... I didn't set the label.text to anything..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the viewcontroller, select the label and on the right side, you should be able to set an image to the label.
Also, you might be having a problem with layers... [self addChild: label z:0 tag:1];
Just in case you don't know, z:0 means the layer. So something with z:-1 would be below a picture with z:0. You could just set the text ontop of the label